# Change names in symbols into letter names

Tags: microsoft-excel, symbols

I'm working with population data in Vietnam. I've downloaded a series of cities and their corresponding population densities on the NASA SEDAC website. The issue is when I open the document, all the Vietnamese names are in symbols, maybe due to the different alphabet. Is there a way to make the symbols change into their corresponding letter?

[image]

Comment: Use a font that supports those characters. Also make sure your are using the correct text encoding

Comment: It may be more than just switching to a supporting font: the NASA database may have mangled the encoding and the export may have mangled the encoding. So if you use a typeface with vietnamese support and still see glyph issues, look into the encoding and code page on the NASA database and also the format used for export.

Comment: @Guillaume You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) - you should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a blank excel doc, went to "Data" > "Select from text" > Went to chose my Vietnamese Excel Doc --> Import. Then a dialog box opens: in the top left dropdown list entitled "origin of folder" select "none". My symbols were transformed in english letters